# Ошибка при запуске ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

При запуске ubuntu появляется черный экран, где написано ucsi_acpi USB000:00: error -ETIMEOUT: PPM init failed
Что делать?

Comment: Например: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225934/ucsi-acpi-ppm-init-failed-110

Comment: Хотя может надо именно про USB ошибку гуглить, там немного другое вылазит